# iPhone : Memory warning destroying strong objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, viewdidload, didreceivememorywarning

I am developing an app with a view to take pictures.

I faced a very strange behavior lately, here is my code.

```
@interface ViewControllerPhotos : UIViewController 
@property (strong) NSString* _albumID;
@end

@implementation ViewControllerPhotos
@synthesize _albumID;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   return;
   // commented or not : give the same issue
   //    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

    self._albumID = [Tools generateUUID];

    NSLog(@"new photoset : local UUID \"%@\"", self._photoSetLocalID);
}

@end
```

My issue is : if there is a memory warning, the UID stored in `_albumID` is forgotten and regenerated so my album is broken in two. Why ? Should not the `strong` keyword be able to keep the current value ?

Or is it because the `viewDidload` is called again ? If it's the case then how to be sure we load our view for the first time for a proper init ? The methods sounded to be designed for it.

Comment: Objects are strong by default, so the strong keyword does nothing here. Try writing your albumID to file and retrieving it when you receive a memory warning.

Comment: `if(!self._albumID || [self._albumID isEqualToString:@""])      self._albumID=[Tools generateUUID];` in `viewDidLoad` solved it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could figure this out with the debugger and the manual, but...

`viewDidLoad` is called when the view loads. In a low memory situation when the viewcontroller is not visible, the view may be unloaded. There's a `viewDidUnload` method in iOS3+. Then when you press the back button and the view becomes visible again, `viewDidLoad` would be called again as you suspected.

The way around this is either to store the UUID so when its reloaded it's not re-*generated*.

Or, you could put the assignment in the `init` method. That way it's only ever called once.

Comment: indeed `viewDiLoad` is called again but `init`. This means every view should init themselves from the `init` method but in this case some graphical parameters like `frame` are not available. This is a weird way of dealing with memory warnings, yet maybe the best, but it seems there is a lack of documentation on it!